# Toughness on animal companion

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, animals

Just wondering if I take toughness at level one do I just get the +3hp or do I get the +3hp plus 1 additional HP per HD and since he has two HD at level 1 does that mean 3 + 2 HP for a total of 5? :O could someone provide some clarity on this one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Toughness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/toughness-final/) feat reads

> Benefit: You gain +3 hit points. **For every Hit Die you possess beyond 3**, you gain an additional +1 hit point. If you have more than 3 Hit Dice, you gain +1 hit points whenever you gain a Hit Die (such as when you gain a level).

Emphasis mine.

If the animal companion only has 2 HD they would only gain the +3 HP. Once they reach 4 HD they would have a total of +4 HP, 5HD would give them 5 HP, ect. The easist way to think of the feat is after 3 Hit Die/Levels the character gains an extra hit point.

Comment: The best way to think of the Toughness feat is that it grants you +1 HP per HD, capped at a minimum of 3. The awkward wording that it has is probably because the original version of the feat in D&D only granted the flat +3 HP bonus (and was therefore an awful trap option).

Comment: @Carcer And then they had the Improved Toughness feat introduced in the video games such as Neverwinter Nights, which gave 1 HP per HD (and was not, as the name might make you think, a chain of feats with Toughness, but rather a replacement).  This new version of toughness is just combining the two such that you always take the higher.